# add check box to multi select drop down list in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I found code on here to create a multi select drop down list in google sheets, I would like to be able to add a checkbox to the front of each item in the list so that a user could check or uncheck it to add it to the list.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCfRt.png)

Currently with my code they can not duplicate items in the list (which is good) but they also have to delete the contents of the cell and start over if they accidentally chose the wrong item.

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  var oldValue;
  var newValue;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (activeCell.getColumn() == 25 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "MasterData") {
    newValue = e.value;
    oldValue = e.oldValue;
    if (!e.value) {
      activeCell.setValue("");
    }
    else {
      if (oldValue.indexOf(newValue) < 0) {
        activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ',\n' + newValue);
      }
      else {
        activeCell.setValue(oldValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function insertCheckboxes(startrow = 2, column = 5) {
  if (startrow && column) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName("MasterData");
    sh.insertColumnBefore(column)
    sh.getRange(startrow, column, sh.getLastRow() - startrow + 1).insertCheckboxes();
  }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get that to work.  I am a noob.  Do I need to specify where I want it to start?function insertCheckboxes(startrow,column) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("MasterData");
  sh.getRange(2,25,sh.getLastRow() - startrow + 1).insertCheckboxes();
}   I got an error about number of rows in range must be at least one.    also do i need to add this to my code allowing the multiselect? I am assuming i would i just dont know where i am having issues running more than one function at a time.